# How can I attach a timestamp to an npmbuild?

Tags: npm, webpack, gulp, npm-scripts

I am just getting my head around npm and creating build with npm/webpack/build. 
How can I add a timestamp as part of the filename to a bundle.js that is generated with npm/webpack? Is there a module available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no existing module that I'm aware of. However, this can be achieved using the following solution:

1. Write a custom nodejs script to append the timestamp to the resultant `bundle.js`, i.e. rename the file to something like: `bundle-2018-02-14-10-16-22.js`.
2. Utilize [npm-scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) [`post`](http://www.marcusoft.net/2015/08/pre-and-post-hooks-for-npm-scripting.html) hook to invoke the custom nodejs script.

*Note: I'm assuming that you execute the `npm run build` command to produce `bundle.js`. In which case the solution below utilizes an npm-script named `"postbuild"` to invoke the nodejs script which appends the timestamp.*

---

**timestamp.js**

Create a custom nodejs script as follows. Let's name the file `timestamp.js`.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const src = process.argv[2];

if (!src) {
  throw new Error('Missing file path argument');
}

const tstamp = new Date().toISOString()
    .replace(/\.[\w\W]+?$/, '') // Delete from dot to end.
    .replace(/\:|\s|T/g, '-');  // Replace colons, spaces, and T with hyphen.

const ext = path.extname(src);
const fname = path.basename(src).replace(ext, '');
const fpath = path.dirname(src);

const dest = path.join(fpath, `${fname}-${tstamp}${ext}`);

fs.rename(src, dest, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

---

**package.json**

In the `scripts` section of your `package.json` add a `postbuild` script to invoke `timestamp.js` as follows:

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": ... ,
    "postbuild": "node timestamp path/to/bundle.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

Note: your current `build` script should remain as-is.

---

**Running**

When executing the `npm run build` command your build steps will run as normal. Upon completion the `postbuild` script will automatically be invoked, appending the timetsamp to the file name as necessary.

---

**Notes**

- The `path/to/bundle.js` part in the `postbuild` script should be changed to the actual path where your resultant `bundle.js` file is created.
- The example `postbuild` script above currently assumes `timestamp.js` resides in the same directory as `package.json`. You could, *(for example)*, save it in a hidden directory named `.scripts` which resides in the same directory as `package.json`. In which case your `postbuild` script would need to be changed to:

  ```json
  {
    ...
    "scripts": {
      "build": ... ,
      "postbuild": "node .scripts/timestamp path/to/bundle.js"
    },
    ...
  }
  ```
- The timestamp appended to the file name currently uses the format: `YYYY-MM-DD-hh-mm-ss`.
- You'll notice that [ES6 Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are utilized in `timestamp.js` at the line reading:

  ```json
  const dest = path.join(fpath, `${fname}-${tstamp}${ext}`);
  ```

  However, if the version of *node* your running doesn't support these, then replace that line with the following (i.e. use the `+` operator for string concatenation instead):

  ```json
  const dest = path.join(fpath, fname + '-' + tstamp + ext);
  ```